# Getting the current state of a semantics accordion in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, semantic-ui

Semantic accordion is driving me crazy!
Does someone know if there is a way of getting the current state of an accordion (e.g. open or closed) when implemented in Meteor?
If I understood correctly I should create a function in the .js file inside section Template.foo.helpers. What I did so far is:

```
    isOpen : function() {
        var cState = $('.ui.accordion').currentState();
        return cState=='open';
    }
```

This should return true if the accordion is open and false otherwise, but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to do such a job?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: open the console and run the line: $('.ui.accordion').currentState(); Also, in general use === (but that doesn't matter here). This isn't a meteor specific problem.

Comment: Console returns "not a function", but @saimeunt gave me the right solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your helper does not reference a reactive data source, which means it won't be re-executed whenever the state of the accordion is changed.

You can fix this by using Semantic UI accordion plugin callbacks to track the current state of the widget and store it as a reactive data source.

```
Template.accordion.onCreated(function(){
  // you'll need to meteor add reactive-var to use this
  this.opened = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.accordion.onRendered(function(){
  // store a reference to the template instance to use it later
  // in functions where the this keyword will be bound to something else
  var template = this;
  this.$(".ui.accordion").accordion({
    onOpen:function(){
      // here, the this keyword is bound to the currently opened item
      template.opened.set(true);
    },
    onClose:function(){
      // modify the reactive var accordingly
      template.opened.set(false);
    }
  });
});

Template.accordion.helpers({
  opened:function(){
    // Template.instance().opened is a reactive data source
    // this helper will get re-executed whenever its value is modified
    return Template.instance().opened.get();
  }
});
```

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you thank you thank you! :) My upvote requres 15 reputation which I currently lack (subscribed yesterday) but I swear I will give you all the points I have :)))